# How to pass arguments to a golfscript program from command line

Tags: ruby, arguments, golfscript

I'd like to know how to pass arguments to a golfscript program from the command line. I'm using ruby interpreter that I downloaded from golfscript.com. From what I understood from googling a bit, in ruby you pass arguments like this `ruby ./program.rb 4`, but doing `ruby ./golfscript.rb prnt.gs 4` doesn't work (prints an empty string).

In golfscript the arguments are supposed to be made into a string and pushed to the stack.
`prnt.gs`'s code is just `p` (it's supposed to print the top of the stack - the argument).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Sorry, I wrote that I got an error but actually it just didn't work like it's supposed to. Edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

try running it like this:

```
 >echo 4 | ruby golfscript.rb prnt.gs
```